# "Last spring" in "I took this math course last spring"

Tags: grammar, adverb, time

Suppose I want to say

> I took this math course last spring.

Can I say

> (a) Ich habe letzten Frühling diesen Mathe-Kurs belegt.

or

> (b) Ich habe im letzten Frühling diesen Mathe-Kurs belegt.

or

> (c) Ich habe in dem letzten Frühling diesen Mathe-Kurs belegt.

Comment: Statt "Ich habe ... belegt" empfehle ich "Ich belegte".

Comment: I recommend not to follow @userunknown's advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say either of a) and b). c) is not used, because `in dem` is merged to `im`.

a) is preferred, if you don't want to emphasize, that the course was taken embedded into an atmosphere/environment of spring, but just as an approximate date.

b) would be preferred the other way around.

Comment: I don't feel any difference in meaning between a and b.

Comment: @chirlu There's no essential change in meaning, just verb case (Dat, Akk).

Comment: @Kevin: Agreement. The change in meaning is only a slight one, no essential one.